# inline-block 50% elements don't resize evenly

Tags: html, resize, percentage, css

I have 2 inline-block divs with 50% widths. They both have 2 buttons each with 140px widths.

My expectation was that since elements are both equal in width they should also resize at the same time. What happens now is that when the containing div gets small enough so that the four buttons dont fit any more they wrap and the 2 divs resize, but before they resize equally one div gets smaller. It's best illustrated in the jsfiddle. If you resize the browser window slowly you will see one div resizing before the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/dominicm/pcYhL/2/

HTML white-space is removed with comments and margin and padding are all set to 0.

What could be causing this and how to fix it? Any other suggestions on how to achieve the layout shown in jsfiddle?

Here's the code for reference in case jsfiddle isn't available later.

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div id="d">
      <input class="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Selected"><input class="collapse" type="button" value="Collapse All">
  </div><!--
  --><div id="p">
      <input class="expand" name="expand" type="button" value="Expand All">
  <input class="update" type="submit" value="Update Selected">
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background-color:#666;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#d{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#p{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.delete{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:140px;
}
.update{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:140px;
}
.collapse{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:140px;
}
.expand{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:140px;
}
```

Comment: At some point are you expecting the green container to float underneath of the red container?

Comment: Yes, but I will get that functionality by adding min-width:~140px(size of single button)

Comment: If i'm right, you want to see INPUT on 2 lines at the same time while resizing. I can make it works when using the "<!-- -->" trick you use with DIV but with both INPUT in each DIV.

Comment: Thats correct but I already use <!-- -->. So Unless I made a mistake that's not the issue. Feel free to edit the fiddle.

Comment: I mis-understood what you meant. I now see that one of my input pairs were not on the same line and that caused the issue. Add it as an Answer pls. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason one was collapsing before the other was due to the differences in the HTML formatting.

You had both buttons inline (no line-break) in the green box, and in the red box they were separated with a line break.  Here are the differences I'm referring to:

View the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcYhL/14/

These buttons are not separated by a line-break or space:

```
<div id="d">
     <input class="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Selected"><input class="collapse" type="button" value="Collapse All">
</div>
```

But these ones are...

```
<div id="p">
     <input class="expand" name="expand" type="button" value="Expand All">
     <input class="update" type="submit" value="Update Selected">
</div>
```

If you change the second one to this:

```
<div id="p">
     <input class="expand" name="expand" type="button" value="Expand All"><input class="update" type="submit" value="Update Selected">
</div>
```

You will noticed they collapse at the exact same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is still white space between the buttons in the second div.

```
  <input class="expand" name="expand" type="button" value="Expand All">
 <input class="update" type="submit" value="Update Selected">
```

Put them on the same line and you should be good.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcYhL/13/

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I am 100% clear as to what the issue is. But I think this should fix your problem. Add `min-width:140px;` to your containers.

```
#d{
    width:50%;
    min-width:140px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#p{
    width:50%;
    min-width:140px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcYhL/6/

If you are expecting the buttons to re-size as the containers re-size then you will need to use percentages for the widths of the buttons.

```
.delete{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:70%;
}
.update{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:70%;
}
.collapse{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:70%;
}
.expand{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:70%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcYhL/10/

Comment: That makes the divs wrap which I do want but that's not the issue. To see the problem you need to resize BROWSER window(not jsfiddle frame) slowly. You will see the of the divs(green/yellow) to resize before the other div. You will see one div will have 2 buttons aligned vertically and other div will have buttons aligned horizontally. If you continue resizing it resizes to equal dimensions. Issue is that small gap in non-equal resizing.

Comment: No, I am not expecting buttons to resize btw.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Okay that is what I am using to. Also I see no yellow div. I see red/green. And by the other div are you referring to the gray div?

Comment: I meant green/red. The issue was actually that one of my input pairs were not on the same line which caused white space to resize one of the divs before the other one.

Comment: Okay glad you figured it out. Sorry I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.